# Is there any simple way to check radio buttons when page loads, based on the what is checked before the page submit?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using django.

My webpage works like this, If i check the radio button and click on submit. it redirects to the same page with jobs redefined on the basis of which radiobuttons were checked. My problem is after loading the page none of the radio buttons are checked.

so I would like to know is there any method so that when redirect the same page(ie `form action=""`) the previous selected radio buttons(ie before submit) are selected in this page too?

Comment: Sounds like you want to make a form for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since requests are stateless, you will have to somehow "save" the state of your radio buttons. One option would be to use sessions, the other would be to use a form and instantiate it with the submitted data.